# How to force view update onAppear in swift ui

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to view content view onAppear? The method is called, but list does not updated
Seems it should be some way to do this

```
import SwiftUI

var texts = ["0", "0", "0"]

struct ContentView: View {


  var body: some View {
      List {
        Text(texts[0])
        Text(texts[1])
        Text(texts[2])

      }
      .onAppear(){
        texts[0] = "1"
        print(texts)
    }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to cause a re-render you need to use state.

If you bring the `texts` variable inside the `ContentView` struct and declare it as `@State` then it will cause the `ContentView` to re-render.

Note you will have to use `self` in the `onAppear` as you are referencing `texts` in a closure.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var texts = ["0", "0", "0"] . // Apple suggests that these should be private

  var body: some View {
      List {
        Text(texts[0])
        Text(texts[1])
        Text(texts[2])

      }
      .onAppear(){
        self.texts[0] = "1"
        print(self.texts)
      }
    }
}
```

---

If however you are wanting to share the `texts` across multiple views then you will need create an environment object. You can do this as follows:

Create an ObservableObject.

```
class Texts: ObservableObject {
    @Published var texts = ["0", "0", "0"] // You can obviously choose whichever name you want for this variable.
}
```

Then in your SceneDelegate create an instance of this object and attach it to your ContentView.

```
let texts = Texts()
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(texts)
```

Then in `ContentView.swift` you can use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var texts: Texts

  var body: some View {
      List {
        // notice that you have to access the texts array that is stored in texts object
        Text(texts.texts[0])
        Text(texts.texts[1])
        Text(texts.texts[2])

      }
      .onAppear(){
        self.texts.texts[0] = "1"
        print(self.texts.texts)
       }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environmentObject(Texts())
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I use ObservedObject in my view instead of EnvironmentObject

Comment: Yeah `ObservedObject` would work too. It really depends on your use case. As you had set the initial value for texts outside the struct and created a global variable it looked as if you were wanting something that would be accessible from everywhere, hence the use of the `EnvironmentObject`.

Answer (score 0):

"texts" should be `@State` if you want the view to update when the variable changes and place it inside the view

```
  @State var texts = ["0", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: My case is more complex than a sample. I should use ObservableObject as a texts and ObservedObject in my view